# Hodge theory on cylindrical end

Tags: hodge-theory

Let $(X,g_0)$ be a compact oriented  Riemannian 4-manifold with boundary $S^3$ and $Y=X\cup [0,\infty)\times S^3$ with metric $g$ which is product on the cylindrical part.

Consider the operator $d^++d^*$, which can be written as $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}+L$, where $L:=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&d^*\\
d&*d\end{array}\right)$. Let $\delta$ be smooth function which vanishes on $Y\setminus [0,\infty)\times S^3$ and $\delta(t,y)=a(t-1)$ for $(t,y)\in\mathbb R\times S^3$, $t\geq1$($a$ is a constant).
On the weighted space $L^p_{1,\delta}(Y)$, we know that if $a$ does not lie in the spectrum of $L$, then $d^++d^*$ is a Fredholm operator.

**Q**: 
1.)
If $a<0$ and greater than the first negative eigenvalue of $L$, why we can say that $\ker(d^++d^*)\cong H^1(Y)$ and $co\ker(d^++d^*)\cong H^0(Y)\oplus H^+(Y)$?

2. )
   If we replace $S^3$ by any other oriented closed 3 manifold, does the above statement still hold?